# Updating an already submitted graduate school application

Tags: graduate-admissions, mathematics

I submitted a graduate school application last week for a Math PhD program at a well-known university in the US. They asked me to submit a PDF list of all the courses that I have taken. I uploaded a list with all the information they asked for, except for the description of each course I simply provided a link to a page on the university's website which gives a detailed syllabus for that course.

In hindsight, I realized that my application might be printed out and hence the links would be useless. But the admissions committee can still get a  sense of what the courses are about from the course name and textbooks used (I provided these).

Should I go back and re-upload my document to include more explicit descriptions? Their application seems to allow post-submission uploads for Fall semester grades and miscellaneous documents (which this PDF list of courses falls under).

There are two reasons why I'm hesitant about doing this.

- They never explicit said that we can submit anything after the deadline. So I suspect that if upload a document past the deadline, they might hold it against me.
- I come from a pretty well-known undergraduate institution, so I don't think a PDF list of courses will change the admissions outcome. I.e. it is not worth the effort.

I could email them, but I'm quite certain they will simply reply with a generic response such as "You cannot change your submission after the deadline."

This might be another case of the so-called "applicant's hypochondria", so I apologize if this is not a good question. I would appreciate hearing someone else's perspective.

Comment: If you don't ask them, you don't learn anything useful. We have no say in what they do.

Comment: Thanks, this was the comment I needed to hear